# How to find the x axis value based on mouse position in svg produced with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As an exercise I am tryint to replicate [this](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/number-with-mental-and-neurodevelopmental-disorders-by-type?time=1993..1999&facet=none) visualization. I have almost everything figured out now but I am stuck on the vertical line with tooltip based on the mouse position.

I have tried to use the xScale to find out the year but it doesn't provide the correct value and I don't know why. The result is different for different time ranges (as chosen by the slider), it is not consistently erroneous by some amount. I know that once I've got the correct year based on the mouse position I'll be able to sort everything else out. Here is my code:

```
import {LinearAxisLeft} from "../../shared/LinearAxisLeft";
import {AxisBottom} from "../../shared/AxisBottom";
import {useState} from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import {CircleMarks} from "../../shared/CircleMarks";

export const MultilineChart = ({
                                   data,
                                   xScale,
                                   xValue,
                                   yScale,
                                   yValue,
                                   innerWidth,
                                   innerHeight,
                                   xTickFormat,
                                   yTickFormat,
                                   colorScale,
                                   colorValue,
                                   marksRadius,
                                   fadeOpacity,
                                   hoveredValue
                               }) => {

    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const colors = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf"]

    const disorders = new Set(data.map(d => d.disorder));

    const data_by_disorder = [...disorders].map(d => {
        return data.filter(x => x.disorder === d);
    });

    const line = d3.line()
        .x(d => xScale(new Date(d.year, 0)))
        .y(d => yScale(d.cases));

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (hovered) {
            let x = e.clientX;
            let year = xScale.invert(x).getFullYear()
            console.log(year)
        }
    }

    const filteredData = data_by_disorder.flat().filter(d=> (d.disorder === hoveredValue))


    return (
        <>
            <rect width={innerWidth} height={innerHeight} fill="white" opacity={0} onMouseOver={(e) => setHovered(true)}
                  onMouseMove={(e) => handleMouseMove(e)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}/>
            <LinearAxisLeft
                yScale={yScale}
                innerWidth={innerWidth}
                tickFormat={yTickFormat}
            />
            <AxisBottom
                xScale={xScale}
                innerHeight={innerHeight}
                tickFormat={xTickFormat}
            />
            <g opacity={hoveredValue ? fadeOpacity : 1}>
                {data_by_disorder.map((d, i) =>
                    <path key={i} fill="none" stroke={colorScale(colorValue(d[0]))} strokeWidth={3} d={line(d)}/>
                )}
                <CircleMarks data={data_by_disorder.flat()}
                             xScale={xScale}
                             xValue={xValue}
                             yScale={yScale}
                             yValue={yValue}
                             radius={marksRadius}
                             colorScale={colorScale}
                             colorValue={colorValue}
                             tooltip={false}
                />
            </g>
            <g opacity={hoveredValue ? fadeOpacity : 1}>
                {data_by_disorder.map((d, i) =>
                    <path key={i} fill="none" stroke={colorScale(colorValue(d[0]))} strokeWidth={1.5} d={line(d)}/>
                )}
                <CircleMarks data={data_by_disorder.flat()}
                             xScale={xScale}
                             xValue={xValue}
                             yScale={yScale}
                             yValue={yValue}
                             radius={marksRadius}
                             colorScale={colorScale}
                             colorValue={colorValue}
                             tooltip={false}
                />
            </g>
            {filteredData.length > 0 &&
                <>
                    <path fill="none" stroke={colorScale(colorValue(filteredData[0]))} strokeWidth={1.5} d={line(filteredData)}/>
                    <CircleMarks data={filteredData}
                                 xScale={xScale}
                                 xValue={xValue}
                                 yScale={yScale}
                                 yValue={yValue}
                                 radius={marksRadius}
                                 colorScale={colorScale}
                                 colorValue={colorValue}
                                 tooltip={false}
                    />
                </>
            }

            ));

        </>
    )
}
```

Here is the screenshot of what is produced when I hover over the `1994` point.

[image]

Could you help me to figure out what is wrong with my onMouseMove function?